# How to get the data from DatePicker in real time?

Tags: android, datepicker

How can i get the month and the day when i scroll the DatePicker?
(I don't want to use Dialogs).
It's possible to send the time from DatePicker to TextView in real time when i scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Just set an `onDateChangedListener` on the date picker. This will get called as the date changes and you can do whatever you would like with the data.

Comment: In your question you had just asked if the data from the DatePicker can be sent to a TextView. Just convert the data to a string and use `TextView.setText(dateString)`.